lwc:if and @api decorated
let's say we've got some template
<template>
<span>target - {isTarget} -</span>

<template lwc:if={isTarget}>
    <c-migration-targets></c-migration-targets>  
</template>

in one component and
   <template>
   <lightning-card>
    <lightning-layout vertical-align="start" class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <lightning-layout-item size="6" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12" padding="around-small">
            <c-migration-tool is-target=false></c-migration-tool>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="6" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12" padding="around-small">
            <c-migration-tool is-target=true></c-migration-tool>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
   </lightning-card>
</template>

on the other
but lwc:if={isParent} doesn't work even thou  target - {isTarget} - shows the correct value declared as
@api isTarget;
what did i missed?

Try adding some extra content (e.g., some text) that is guaranteed to render inside the <template lwc:if={isTarget}>.  It's possible that the template is rendering but the child component isn't.

the sutiation is really strange - i can see the contents of child component in both cases

In modern HTML (and LWC), a Boolean property is true when included in the element and false when it isn't;  your test <c-migration-tool is-target=false> should just be <c-migration-tool> and <c-migration-tool is-target=true> should just be <c-migration-tool is-target>.  When you need to bind it to a boolean JS property, then you can assign binding, like is-target={property}.

@JasonClark This should be an answer (and I don't want to steal the rep you'd get).

In modern HTML (and LWC), a Boolean property is true when included in the element and false when it isn't; your line
<c-migration-tool is-target=false></c-migration-tool>

should just be
<c-migration-tool></c-migration-tool>

and
<c-migration-tool is-target=true></c-migration-tool>

should just be
<c-migration-tool is-target></c-migration-tool>

When you need to bind to a boolean JS property, then you can assign a binding.
<c-migration-tool is-target={property}></c-migration-tool>

